# SyntaxError: Unexpected token Y at Object.parse (native)

Tags: angularjs, spring-boot

I am uploading a file using spring boot and angular js but when i click on import i have the erros mentioned in the title.

Here's my controller js

```
    var app=angular.module("MyCat",[]);
    app .directive("fileread", [function () 
                    { return { scope: { fileread: "=" }, link: function (scope, element, attributes) 
                    { element.bind("change", function (changeEvent)

                            { scope.$apply(function () { scope.fileread = changeEvent.target.files[0];
                             }); }); } } }]);                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                   // } }
//Upload files
        $scope.upload=function(){

                var fd = new FormData();
                var url="http://localhost:8080/upload";
                fd.append("file", $scope.rap.file);
                fd.append("name",$scope.rap.name);
               $http.post(url,fd,{
                   transformRequest: angular.identity,
                   headers: {'Content-Type': undefined}
               })
               .success(function(){
               })
               .error(function(){
               });

        }
```

Here's my java controller

```
upload Files

    @RequestMapping(value="/upload",headers=("content-type=multipart/*"),consumes = {"multipart/form-data"}, method=RequestMethod.POST)
    public @ResponseBody String handleFileUpload(@RequestParam("name") String name,@RequestParam("file") MultipartFile file){
        if (!file.isEmpty()) {
            try {
                byte[] bytes = file.getBytes();
                BufferedOutputStream stream =
                        new BufferedOutputStream(new FileOutputStream(new File(name)));
                stream.write(bytes);
                stream.close();
                return "You successfully uploaded " + name + "!";
            } catch (Exception e) {
                return "You failed to upload " + name + " => " + e.getMessage();
            }
        } else {
            return "You failed to upload " + name + " because the file was empty.";
        }
    }
```

Here's  my html page

```
<section id="contact-page">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="center">        

            <p class="lead">Import reports</p>
        </div> 
        <div class="row contact-wrap"> 
            <div class="status alert alert-success" style="display: none"></div>
            <form id="main-contact-form" class="contact-form" name="contact-form" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data" >
                <div class="col-sm-5 col-sm-offset-1">
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label>name *</label>
                        <input type="text" name="name" class="form-control" required="required" ng-model="rap.name">
                    </div>
                   <div class="form-group">  
                        <label>DateOfUploade</label>
                        <input type="Date" class="form-control" ng-model="rap.dateOfUpload" >
                    </div>
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label for="t">Type of File</label>
                            <select 
                                class="form-control" id="t" ng-model="rap.type">
                                <option>.word</option>
                                <option>.xsl</option>
                                <option>.pdf</option>
                            </select>
                        </div> 

                        <div class="form-group">
                        <label>file</label>
                        <input type="file" name="file" class="form-control" fileread="rap.file">
                    </div>                        

                    <div class="form-group">
                        <button type="submit"  class="btn btn-primary btn-lg"  ng-click="upload()">Import File</button>
                    </div>

                </div> 
                    <table class="table">
                        <tr>
                            <th>NameOfUploader</th>
                            <th>DateOfUpload</th>
                            <th>TypeOfFile</th>
                            <th>File</th>
                        </tr>
                        <tr ng-repeat="rap in reports">
                            <td>{ {rap.NameOfUploader}}</td>
                            <td>{ {rap.DateOfUpload}}</td>
                            <td>{ {rap.TypeOfFile}}</td>
                            <td>{ {rap.File}}</td>
                        </tr>
                    </table> 

                </form> 
        </div><!--/.row-->
    </div><!--/.container-->
</section><!--/#contact-page-->
enter code here
```

Any ideas ?

Comment: Your controller is returning a literal string, but you need a JSON object.

Comment: How shall i do that, can you explain please

Comment: That's pretty broad; it's not clear to me what you are even trying to do with the response.

Comment: I want to consume the rest service with angularjs to upload files

Comment: Okay, but what I mean is that I can't tell what your code is supposed to be doing with the response. It's hard for me to give you much guidance, but maybe somebody more familiar with angular can help you more than I can.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unexpected token 'Y' - is starting of your message from java controller 'You successfully ...' that comes from the server instead of valid JSON string. Try to return something parseable: `{"result": "You successfully bla-bla-bla..."}`

Comment: Any help please.I'am blocked :/

Comment: OK, what you need is to find JSON.parse command that gives you this error and print what string it tries to parse.

Comment: I don't have the command Json.parse at all in my code ,The problem is taht i have a method in the java controller wich the type of return is string and not json .

Comment: I resolved the pb i modify the type of the method in java controller from string to boolean ans magically it works :D

Comment: it works as Magomogo said, just escape the quotes ex: return "{\"upload\":\"success\"}";